# Can't get java code to print

Tags: java

The compiler says that the build is successful, but when I compile it, it doesn't print out any results. Not sure what is wrong. What can I do to fix it.

```
 public class sixseven {
public static void main(String [] args){
    //initiation
     int m = 2;
     int n= 3; 
     //call for method

    ack(m,n);

}  

    public static int ack(int m, int n) {


if (m < 0 || n < 0) {
   System.out.println("Number not allowed: ");
}

if (m == 0) {
    return n + 1;

} else if (n == 0) {
    return ack(m-1, 1); 

} else {
    return ack(m-1, ack(m,n-1));
      }
        }
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't print anything because you don't have any code that tells it to print. It calculates "ack" returns it, and then it's done, because a program doesn't do anything more than you tell it to do. Replace the line

```
ack(m,n);
```

with something like

```
System.out.println("Answer: " + ack(m,n));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main method you haven't printed out the returning value ack(m,n) statement should be inside a print method